# Preserve Last modified date when uploading file using FluentFtp

Tags: .net, file-upload, ftp, fluentftp

I have seen similar questions in the past but not directly related to FluentFtp NuGet package.

How can I keep the last modified date from the sender to the receiver when I am uploading a single file?

Looks like the default is not to preserve it, is there anyway of doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

FluentFtp won't do it for you. You have to code that yourself. Use [`FtpClient.SetModifiedTime`](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/File-Management):

```cs
ftpClient.SetModifiedTime(remotePath, File.GetLastWriteTime(localPath));
```

---

*But first, make sure your FTP server supports it. Check if any GUI/commandline FTP client can preserve timestamps of the uploaded files on your server.*